# Magento 2: Display Active Paymet methods in configuration

Tags: magento2

I am working on one custom extension in Magento2 and I need to show the active payment methods in the backend configuration of the extension with multi select option. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

i hope below code will help you

```
$paymentM = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Payment\Model\MethodList');

        $quote = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface');
        $res=$paymentM->getAvailableMethods($quote);
        foreach($res as $re){
            echo $re->getCode().'<br>';

        }
```

if it work accept it

Comment: Thank you for the answer, one query, tried above code but getting "Fatal error call to a member function create() on null in file. Can you specify which object is this? _objectManager.
Do we need to specify or declare this? If so then with what?

Comment: Finally done it with the code mentioned in the blog
https://magecomp.com/blog/get-active-payment-methods-with-multi-select-in-backend/

Answer (score 0):

`\Magento\Payment\Helper\Data` class provide set of methods to get available payment methods